# Conway's Game Of Life In C

Tags: c, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I have made a version of conways game of life in C, using a 2d array which should wrap around the sides. Unfortunately all that happens is the numbers flick back and forth between 1 and 0 with no clear pattern. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int const WIDTH = 100;
    int const HEIGHT = 100;
    int const CYCLES = 1000;
    int grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    int temp[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    int row;
    int col;
    for(row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++){
            grid[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }

    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    int neighbours;
    for(i = 0; i < CYCLES; i++){
        for(row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++){
                temp[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
        for(row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++){
                neighbours = 0;
                for(y = -1; y < 2; y++){
                    for(x = -1; x < 2; x++){
                        if(x != 0 && y != 0 && grid[(row + y) % HEIGHT][(col + x) % WIDTH] == 1){
                            neighbours++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(grid[row][col] == 1){
                    if(neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3){
                        temp[row][col] = 0;
                    }else{
                        temp[row][col] = 1;
                    }
                }else if(grid[row][col] == 0){
                    if(neighbours == 3){
                        temp[row][col] = 0;
                    }else{
                        temp[row][col] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++){
                grid[row][col] = temp[row][col];
                printf("%d", grid[row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking over the code for a problem now but I suggest making some functions to help make this more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do notice one problem.

The 4th rule states that a dead cell should become alive again if it has exactly 3 neighbors. Currently, your code does the opposite

```
else if(grid[row][col] == 0){
    if(neighbours == 3){
        temp[row][col] = 0;
    }else{
        temp[row][col] = 1;
    }
}
```

This will leave the cell dead if there are exactly 3 and make it alive when that is not the case. Switch the 1 and the 0 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The way you count your neighbors is false (what about `-1%HEIGHT` for example???). I suppose that you want to use a torus (leftmost column connected to rightmost column and the same for lines), so you need to make special cases for borders. A trick is to use modulus like the following.

Suppose you have a line of length `N`, then for each `x` from `0` to `N-1`, compute `mid=x+N`, get neighbors as `left=mid-1` and `right=mid+1`, then count neighbors with `grid(left%N)`, `grid(mid%N)`, `grid(right%N)` (add second dimension the same way of course). So you will catch the torus property without any special cases...

If you want to be sure that it works as expected, I can suggested you to initialize the grid to a well-known GOL pattern (a simple glider for example).

Also verify that the GOL rules are the right ones.